# How to keep a selection of column/rows while scrolling columns and rows on a rmarkdown HTML table?

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown

The goal is to imitate the "freeze columns and rows in Excel" in an HTML table within an RMardown document.

Here is an example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
rmarkdown::paged_table(mtcars)
```
````

The ouput is a HTML document with this table:

[image]

When you click on "Next", to scroll rows, it keeps the column names on top of the table:

[image]

However, when you click on the triangle symbol on the right of the column names, to scroll the columns, the rownames disapear:

[image]

**1. How to keep rownames while scrolling columns?**

**2. How to choose the row(s)/column(s) kept while scrolling?**

I was not able to find this option in `knitr::kable()`, `rmarkdown::paged_table()` nor `flextable`, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to the first question

you can use [`FixedColumns`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) extension of `DataTable` (i.e. using the `{DT}` package) to fix the row names (1st column) while scrolling horizontally.

````
---
title: "fixed columns"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
DT::datatable(
  mtcars, 
  extensions = 'FixedColumns',
  options = list(
    dom = 't',
    scrollX = TRUE,
    fixedColumns = TRUE
  )
)
```
````

Comment: I completely overlooked these DT extensions. Many thanks for highlighting them!